# Support for XmlRoot, XmlAttribute, and XmlElement in Catel ModelBase.Load?

Tags: c#, serialization, catel

I am running into an issue with derived classes from ModelBase.  I'd like to seralize and deseiralize them however I also want to map the xml attributes to properties using XmlAttribute and XmlElement.  Right now, I cannot seem to get this to work with any classes that are derived from ModelBase.

- When I use the standard XmlSerialize, I get no values base
- If I remove the base class and use XmlSerialiez, everything works
- Using ModelBase.Load<>() also doe not work

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

The serialization engine in Catel respects the XmlElement and XmlAttribute attributes (see these [unit tests](https://github.com/Catel/Catel/blob/ae19280b6eae9d96262456e27b3a6dccd9ddba58/src/Catel.Test/Catel.Test.NET40/Data/ModelBaseFacts.serialization.cs#L377) for prove).

If you would like to add support for XmlRoot, please create an issue in the official issue tracker:

http://www.catelproject.com/support/issue-tracker

Comment: I'd be happy to -- one question, how do I create an issue :)  Seems like registering is not enough?

Comment: After registering you should be able to create issues. There should be a large "Create issue" button at https://catelproject.atlassian.net/secure/Dashboard.jspa

Comment: That was what I expected, however I do not have that button. It seems I only have read-only access.  The account id is: ravensorb if that helps.

Comment: Should be fixed now, sorry for the inconvenience.